# what is grey.cols-1 and grey.rows -1 with two for loop

Tags: c++, c, opencv

> can some one help me to explain this code below, what for the each looping? and why grey.rows - 1 and grey.cols - 1?

```
    for(int y = 1; y < grey.rows - 1; y++){
        for(int x = 1; x < grey.cols - 1; x++){
```

Comment: Without any extra context NO ONE is going to be able to answer this for you!

Comment: Obviously the code is avoiding the edges of the 2d array.

Comment: sorry, i'm from indonesian. i can not speak english well to expalain it for detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the array:

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 5;
int array[][5] = { 
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
}; //as an illustrative example of what elements would be processed.
```

The array in question has five elements, since it iterates from index 1 to last index - 1, it would avoid the first and last element of the current array.

So all that would be iterated over in this case would be the 0's in the center.

Comment: thank u profan, its clearly

Comment: please explain again about it... for(int y = 0; y < grey.rows; y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < grey.cols; x++)
                dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;